# Matlab function to compare the elements of two strings

Tags: matlab

I want to write a Matlab function that compares the elements of two strings, so that given a single cell array of strings, it will return that single cell array but in alphabetical order eg `function({'car','apple','bus'})` so I have written a sub-function that compares the elements of two strings against one another and assigns a numerical value:

```
function [ out ] = comparestrings( a,b )

for k=1:min(length(a),length(b))

    if a(1,k)<b(1,k)
       out=1;
       return
    elseif b(1,k)<a(1,k)
        out=0;
        return
    end    
end
    if length(a)<length(b)        
       out=1;
    else out=0;      
    end   
end
```

But when I try and run my program in Matlab, it says there is an error in the line

```
if a(1,k) < b(1,k)
```

I have no clue why this could be?

Comment: what is the error? how is your string defined? if it is a vector of kx1 then there might be size mismatch.

Comment: This is purely a programming question. It probably fits better at StackOverflow. If you want we can migrate the question for you.

Comment: @WillieWong Oh right, sorry I didn't realise. That'd be great, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Functions like `sort`, `unique`, and `ismember` are defined not only for numbers, but also for cell arrays of strings. Therefore, I don't think it is necessary to convert your strings to numbers.

As to your error - you need to supply strings, not cell arrays, i.e.

```
myCellArray = {'car','apple'}

compareStrings(myCellArray{1},myCellArray{2})
```

With the curly brackets, you access the contents of the elements of the cell array, while with parentheses, you'd be supplying cells, and `<` is not defined for cells.

Answer (score 1):

I have run your code in Matlab R2010a under GNU/Linux and it works correctly. I have saved your funcion in a file called `comparestring.m`, and then I can call it the following way:

```
comparestrings('car','apple')

ans =

     0

comparestrings('apple', 'car')

ans =

     1
```

Maybe you are not calling your function properly?

Anyway if you do not need to create a function yourself you can use Matlab's built-in function `sort`:

```
sort({'car','apple','bus'})

ans = 

    'apple'    'bus'    'car'
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, there is a function in matlab called strcmp that does that!